# a java library for manipulating *.properties files

Tags: java

I plan to write a utility for commenting/uncommenting/editing properties inside *.properties files. i know i can read/modify/write those using the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class, but im looking for a library that will let me access things like commented lines, preserve formatting and line order when writing back etc.

does such a library exist?

Comment: why dont u use a File object and modify the properties file. without using properties class.

Comment: @Naveen Babu because properties files have all sorts of gotchas like maximum line length, overflowing lines, mandatory encodings and escaping issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing I am aware of is [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/configuration/). Take a look on [PropertiesConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/index.html).

**EDIT**
Create a [PropertiesConfigurationLayout](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html) object from your properties then you will be able to keep the information about whitespaces and comments. It also will help you to keep track on properties changes